# Object Relational mapping and performance

Tags: java, performance, hibernate

I am currently working on a product that works with `Hibernate` (HQL) and another one that works with `JPQL`. As much as I like the concept of the mapping from a relational structure (database) to an object (Java class), I am not convinced of the performance.

**EXAMPLE**:

**Java**:

```
public class Person{
     private String name;
     private int age;
     private char sex;
     private List<Person> children;

     //...
}
```

I want to get attribute `age` of a certain `Person`. A person with 10 children (he has been very busy). With Hibernate or JPQL you would retrieve the person as an object.

**HQL**:

```
SELECT p
FROM my.package.Person as p
WHERE p.name = 'Hazaart'
```

Not only will I be retrieving the other attributes of the person that I don't need, it will also retrieve all the children of that person and their attributes. And they might have children as well and so on... This would mean more tables would be accessed on database level than needed.

**Conclusion**:

I understand the advantages of Object Relational Mapping. However it would seem that in a lot of cases you will not need every attribute of a certain object. Especially in a complex system. It would seem like the advantages do not nearly justify the performance loss. I've always learned performance should be the main concern.

Can anyone please share their opinion? Maybe I am looking at it the wrong way, maybe I am using it the wrong way...

Comment: Why not select `p.age` if you don't want to load all values of a person?

Comment: @StevenPessall yes in this case that would be better. But my question is more directed towards the general use of the paradigm. In many cases you will select objects.

Comment: I would recommend doing some reading about CQRS (http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html), and providing a specialized Query (the Q from CQRS) where you want a subset of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with JPQL, but if you set up Hiernate correctly, it will not automatically fetch the children. Instead it will return a proxy list, which will fetch the missing data transparently if it is accessed.

This will also work with simple references to other persistent objects. Hibernate will create a proxy object, containing only the ID, and load the actual data only if it is accessed. ("lazy loading")

This of couse has some limitations (like persistent class hierarchies), but overall works pretty good.

BTW, you should use `List<Person>` to reference the children. I'm not sure that Hibernate can use a proxy List if you specify a specific implementation.

**Update:**

In the example above, Hibernate will load the attributes name, age and sex, and will create a `List<Person>` proxy object that initially contains no data.

Once the application accesses calls any method of the List that requires knowledge of the data, like `childen.size()` or iterates over the list, the proxy will call Hibernate to read the children objects and populate the List. The cildren objects, being instances of `Person`, will also contain a proxy `List<Person>` of *their* children.

There are some optimizations hibernate might perform in the background, like loading the children for other Person objects at the same time that might be in this session, since it is querying the database anyways. But whether this is done, and to what extend, is configurable per attribute.

You can also tell hibernate to never use lazy-loading for certain references or classes, if you are sure you'll need them later, or if you continue to use the persistent oject once the session is closed.

Be aware that lazy loading will of course fail if the session is no longer active. If for example you load a Person oject, don't access the children List, and close the session, a call to `children.size()` for example will fail.

IIRC the hibernate session class has method to populate all not-yet-loaded references in a persistent oject, if needed.

Best read the hibernate documentation on how to configure all this.

Comment: Thank you for clearifying the mechanism of lazy loading. I was not aware  of this. Can you explain exactly what attributes would be loaded in my example for the person.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very clear explenation :) I will check documentation on how to configure lazy/eager loading.